# I have installed XAMPP.Now I am trying to install Wordpress and it is asking for a password. I dont understand which password to exactly use here

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

[image]

The above bitnami wordpress module needs a password. I am not aware of which password to give here. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure but here Administration Password means your computer user's password. Check you XAMMP directory may be password protected.

Comment: My computer does not have any password. How can I check my XAMPP directory password protection?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here! You will need to provide the same password that you use when you get this screen.

[OS X Administrator Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTeab.png)

It is the password of the admin user of the system.